# Having trouble determining source of image corruption when converting subsampled blue and red chrominance back to RGB

Tags: c, image, colors, compression, jpeg

Update: Solved issue. My YCbCr to RGB function did not first check for arithmetic over and underflow. Thanks to everyone who replied! I'll leave the problematic code and add my solution in case someone else might benefit from this reminder.
Solution:

```
int willOverflow(int16_t result)
{
  return result > 255;
}
int willUnderflow(int16_t result)
{
  return result < 0;
}

void yCbCrToRgb(uint8_t* yCbCr, uint8_t* targetRgb)
{
    uint8_t luma = yCbCr[0];
    uint8_t Cb = yCbCr[1];
    uint8_t Cr = yCbCr[2];

    if (!willOverflow(luma + (1.402 * (Cr - 128))) && !willUnderflow(luma + (1.402 * (Cr - 128)))) targetRgb[0] = luma + (1.402 * (Cr - 128));
    else targetRgb[0] = willUnderflow(luma + (1.402 * (Cr - 128))) ? 0 : 255;

    if (!willOverflow(luma + (-0.344136 * (Cb - 128)) + (-0.714136 * (Cr - 128))) && !willUnderflow(luma + (-0.344136 * (Cb - 128)) + (-0.714136 * (Cr - 128)))) targetRgb[1] = luma + (-0.344136 * (Cb - 128)) + (-0.714136 * (Cr - 128));
    else targetRgb[1] = willUnderflow(luma + (-0.344136 * (Cb - 128)) + (-0.714136 * (Cr - 128))) ? 0 : 255;

    if (!willOverflow(luma + (1.772 * (Cb - 128))) && !willUnderflow(luma + (1.772 * (Cb - 128)))) targetRgb[2] = luma + (1.772 * (Cb - 128));
    else targetRgb[2] = willUnderflow(luma + (1.772 * (Cb - 128))) ? 0 : 255;
}
```

I am a novice C programmer and a first time poster on stackoverflow, trying to write a jpeg encoder. So far I've managed to convert raw pixel data (read from a .ppm file) into the YCbCr color space, and subsampled the blue and red chrominance in accordance with 4:2:0 subsampling.

The result is a luminance signal that has just as many values as there are pixels in the image, and two chrominance signals that have 1/4 as many. I have had no problem converting from non-subsampled YCbCr back into RGB.

However, when trying to take these three separate channels, recombine them, convert the YCbCr to RGB and write them to an output file, there is very noticeable corruption. Some images it is hardly noticeable, light areas that contrast with darker ones nearby have oddly colored pixels, but the rest of the image appears acceptable. Others have large areas that are acceptable and large areas of corruption. Before I move on to centering these values around zero, and the discrete cosine transform, I want to make sure my subsampling and conversion back to RGB is working properly.

```
// Here are the structures that I am using to represent the images. 
typedef struct ppmHeader
{
  uint32_t numPixels;
  uint16_t pixelWidth, pixelHeight;
  uint8_t maxColorVal;
  size_t headerBytes, pixelDataSize, bytesPerPixel, rowSize;
  uint8_t* headerStr;
} ppmHeader;

typedef struct YCBCR_Pixel_24
{
  uint8_t yCbCr[YCBCR_BYTES]; // 3 bytes
} YCBCR_Pixel_24;

typedef struct intermediateImg
{
  YCBCR_Pixel_24* pixelData; 
  int16_t* lumaSample;
  int16_t* CbSample;
  int16_t* CrSample;
} intermediateImg;
```

```
//This is how I convert from RGB to YCbCr, both the conversion and reverse conversion are from MATLAB
void setYCbCr(YCBCR_Pixel_24* pixel, uint8_t* rgbIn)
{
  uint8_t luminance, Cb, Cr;
  uint8_t r, g, b;

  r = rgbIn[0];
  g = rgbIn[1];
  b = rgbIn[2];

  luminance = 0.257 * r + 0.504 * g + 0.098 * b + 16;
  Cb = -0.148 * r - 0.291 * g + 0.439 * b + 128;
  Cr = 0.439 * r - 0.368 * g - 0.071 * b + 128;

  pixel->yCbCr[0] = luminance;
  pixel->yCbCr[1] = Cb;
  pixel->yCbCr[2] = Cr;
}


// And here is the bulk of the code.

/* 4:2:0 subsampling, for every 4 pixels in a 2x2 block, take one sample of blue and red chrominance. */
void subsampleChrominance(uint16_t imgWidth, uint32_t subSampledSize, intermediateImg* img)
{
  uint32_t ssIndex = 0; //subSample
  uint32_t pdIndex = 0; //pixelData
  
  while (ssIndex < subSampledSize)
  {
    img->CbSample[ssIndex] = img->pixelData[pdIndex].yCbCr[1];
    img->CrSample[ssIndex] = img->pixelData[pdIndex].yCbCr[2];

    if ((pdIndex + 2) % imgWidth == 0)
    {
      pdIndex = (pdIndex + 2) + imgWidth;
    } 
    else pdIndex += 2;

    ssIndex++;
  }
}


/* Pretending we do not have all of the chrominance info, and have to reconstruct the YCbCr field of the image from the 4:2:0 subsampled chrominance signals. */
void writeFromSignals(intermediateImg* img, ppmHeader* imgSpecs, FILE* target)
{
  uint32_t pdIndex, ssIndex, rowCount;
  pdIndex = ssIndex = rowCount = 0;
  uint32_t samplesPerRow = imgSpecs->pixelWidth / 2;

  while (pdIndex < imgSpecs->numPixels)
  {
    img->pixelData[pdIndex].yCbCr[0] = img->lumaSample[pdIndex];
    img->pixelData[pdIndex].yCbCr[1] = img->CbSample[ssIndex];
    img->pixelData[pdIndex].yCbCr[2] = img->CrSample[ssIndex];
    
    if ((pdIndex+1) % imgSpecs->pixelWidth == 0) 
    {
      rowCount++;
      if (rowCount % 2 != 0) ssIndex -= (samplesPerRow-1);
      else ssIndex++;
      pdIndex++;
      continue;
    }

    pdIndex++;
    if (pdIndex % 2 == 0) ssIndex++;
  }
  writeIntermediate_rgb(img, imgSpecs, target);
}

/* Convert YCbCr to rgb and then write it to a file. */
void writeIntermediate_rgb(intermediateImg* img, ppmHeader* specs, FILE* target)
{
  uint32_t i = 0;
  uint32_t sI = 0;
  uint8_t rgb[BYTES_PER_PIXEL_24]; // 3 bytes
  
  fwrite(specs->headerStr, 1, specs->headerBytes, target);
  while (i < specs->numPixels)
  {
    yCbCrToRgb(&img->pixelData[i].yCbCr[0], &rgb[0]);
    fwrite(&rgb[0], 1, BYTES_PER_PIXEL_24, target);
    i++;
    if (i % 2 == 0) sI++;
  }
}

void yCbCrToRgb(uint8_t* yCbCr, uint8_t* targetRgb)
{
  uint8_t luma = yCbCr[0];
  uint8_t Cb, Cr;
  Cb = yCbCr[1];
  Cr = yCbCr[2];
  
  targetRgb[0] = 1.164 * (luma - 16) + 1.596 * (Cr - 128);
  targetRgb[1] = 1.164 * (luma - 16) - 0.813 * (Cr - 128) - 0.392 * (Cb - 128);
  targetRgb[2] = 1.164 * (luma - 16) + 2.017 * (Cb - 128);
}
```

1. The program first reads the image into memory, converting every 3 byte RGB pixel into a 3 byte YCbCr pixel, which is stored in the intermediateImages pixelData field. The Y component is stored in the lumaSample field.
2. Then it calls subSampleChrominance to fill the Cb and Cr sample fields.
3. writeFromSignals is called to rebuild a complete image from the subsampled one.

I have functions that can successfully rebuild and write a perfect looking image from the non-subsampled YCbCr field, but I want to get subsampling working. I understand that subsampling is lossy, but examples I have seen of other images that have been subsampled and converted back to RGB look nearly identical to the uncompressed image. At this point I think it could be very beneficial to have some fresh eyes on my code. It is for a personal project, so I am not in a rush at all.

I will attach a screenshot of a corrupted portion of two images. Outside of a few regions, the images look fine. It is in brighter areas where there seems to be this strange mottling of oddly colored pixels.
[Strange cyan pixels in lighter areas of image. Much better off than the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZkQd.png)
[In this case dark areas of the image contain a lot of noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPmoh.png)

I've checked that I am applying the correct chrominance samples to each block of four pixels, and that does not seem to be the issue. The conversion from YCbCr to RGB works, and the values in all three channels are correct. I tried changing the size of each point in the signal from a signed 16 bit int (which I am using because in the next step I need to center the values around 0, and their range must go from -128 to 128) to an unsigned 8 bit int in case there was something happening with the arithmetic, but had the same output as expected. I am most suspicious of writeFromSignals, although I have tested it on small test images and confirmed that the correct samples are being used for the correct pixels, I have not found a clever way to do so for images with thousands of pixels, and would not be surprised if the pointer arithmetic that I'm using to move around the image is behaving in a way that I did not intend.

I apologize if I am missing something obvious, or have not included adequate information, I am not very familiar with debugging a process like this. I can include the rest of my code, or any other information that might be needed. I greatly appreciate anyone taking the time to look over my code.

Comment: First try to find the smallest possible image that exhibits the corruption, perhaps even 2x2 pixels. Then use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code to see what really happens and where result go wrong.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Make some sample PPM images with **ImageMagick** to test with. Maybe black-red gradient, black-green gradient, black-blue gradient. `magick -size 640x480 gradient:black-red -depth 8 blackred.ppm` or `magick -size 320x240 gradient:lime-black -depth 8 greenblack.ppm`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses! I have some experience with gdb, so I will try what Someprogrammerdude and @MarkSetchell suggested, and see if I can't pin down exactly where problems are happening. To anyone happening upon this, unless you see something that you feel is obvious, it seems I have some good ideas of more things to try on my own for the time being!

Comment: Start with `r=0 g=0 b=1`. Convert to `yCbCr`. Then convert back to `rgb`.  Using your conversion functions, the result was `r=0xff, g=0x00, b=0x00`. So almost black became full red. After you fix that, you'll need to check the other 16777215 combinations to make sure that they all work correctly.

Comment: Aha @user3386109 ! Thanks for narrowing down my search so quickly. I see now that I was trying to cram the result of subtracting 128 from 127 into a byte in that case, and no wonder the dark areas of the pepper picture were turning into such a disaster. Now on to the other 16777215 cases, as you said... :) In all seriousness, I think that was causing all of my problems. I will probably get around to fixing it today or tomorrow and update my post accordingly.